# Apache change domain/service to service.domain

Tags: apache-2.4

I have apache on linux with owncloud on it and I want to access it with **owncloud.domain** and not **domain/owncloud**. For example 
from apache.local/owncloud to owncloud.apache.local
I have apache with IP 192.168.0.103 and proxy with 192.168.0.106.
This is my proxy's config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName http://apache.hcentos.local/
    ServerAlias apache.hcentos.local
    ProxyRequests Off

    #drupal
    ProxyPass /drupal http://192.168.0.103:80/drupal
    ProxyPassReverse /drupal http://192.168.0.103:80/drupal

    #owncloud
    ProxyPass /owncloud http://apache.hcentos.local:80/owncloud
    ProxyPassReverse /owncloud http://apache.hcentos.local:80/owncloud
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to write owncloud.apache.hcentos.local and get to owncloud. Same for drupal.
Please help.

Comment: Please expand your question to include more relevant information. What is the configuration you currently have? Post your sites configuration so we can see what is setup and provide information on how to change it.

Comment: I think you can add a `VirtualHost` directive for the owncloud.domain.com `ServerName` and then use ProxyPass there.

Comment: I understood I  must have two virtual hosts, bud don't know how to configure the thing I am asking

Answer (score 1):

You should be putting the required configuration inside of a `VirtualHost` directive where the `ServerName` directive is configured with the desired hostname: `owncloud.domain`.

Drupal should also be in it's own `VirtualHost` as well.

Within each of these, configure your `ProxyPass` directive to point to the right server/path. You should also add `ProxyPassReverse`.

All of this is documented with examples in Apache's docs:

Apache docs with examples for Revers Proxying: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

Apache docs for VirtualHosts: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/